Using asyncio to initiate multiple background tasks, when each task is synchronous
Considering you have the following code:
import asyncio
import functools

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


async def main():
    background_t = set()
    for i in range(6):
        task = asyncio.create_task(foo1(i))
        background_t.add(task)

async def foo1(i):
  loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
  try:
      await asyncio.wait_for(loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(foo2(), i),60)
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      print("timed out")

def foo2(num):
  # some blocking code

My question if this pattern causes the code to run concurrently in six different tasks when each of them is synchronous operation.

Not runnable due to typos, but code like this does start multiple threads with background tasks. I'd like to add few notes; feel free to skip them if you find I'm stating the obvious - The timeout stops waiting, not the thread. There is the GIL. You don't need asyncio for multi-threading. Your main exits before the work is done.

@VPfb: thanks
timeout stop the waiting - for the relevant task to be finish- but doesn't block other parallel tasks to run foo2 concurrently in the "same" time.
GIL state I think was changed in python 3.11
There is multhireading without asyncio, but for my purpose it is better.
Main exists before jobs are finish, but it doesn't interfere them to finish right? in the background event loop?

when the main stops, a cleanup before exit follows. During that cleanup also a clean shutdown of the executor is attempted. I wouldn't rely on such details. The main really should wait unil the started tasks finish.

@VPFb: can you provide some example how it should wait in main, also there into consideration that instead of 6 tasks I have while true loop that populates the tasks running in the background all the time and the number is increasing

Simpy wait for all tasks in the background_t set. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives and https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently

@VPfB: I was sure that waiting inside inner implementation in the level of :
await asyncio.wait_for(loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(foo2(), i),60)
Would be enough, so If I use will write instead:
async def main():     background_t = set()     for i in range(6):         task = asyncio.create_task(foo1(i))         background_t.add(task)         await asyncio.wait_for(task, 60)
Will it be enough and run all the 6 or the stream tasks concurrently without blocking on each task separately?

Please read the description: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run - asyncio.run will execute the main and then do a cleanup. Your main only starts the tasks and then it exits. All your threads are running during the cleanup of the executor. That was my point. I'm already repating myself: do not exit main until whatever is the program doing is really finished.

Almost there:
the blocking functions are correctly scheduled to run in different threads in the default executor, and some of those will star running, and execute concurrently.
However, there will be only so many of those tasks running as there are workers in the executor - and each of them will take a full worker for the time it is running. (So, if a task is a continuous loop, with no return, or takes more than 60 seconds, it will simply block a worker).
The OS and Python runtime will switch automatically across all running such tasks (even though due to Python limitations up to 3.12 they will only use a single CPU core at a time, and with a special "free threading" build of 3.13 you can use actual parallelism in various cores for free). The problem is that any task scheduled after all workers are busy won't start until there is a free worker - it will just be queued for execution.
If the blocking cause is I/O code, just creating an explicit executor with at least as many workers as there are tasks you want to run in parallel will work they way you plan.
A better strategy, if the workers are to be kept running, is to use an explicit thread for each task, with asyncio.to_thread instead.
And keep in mind that the synchronous functions in other threads have no way to be automatically cancelled: even if the awaitable wrapper call (either run_in_executor or to_thread) is cancelled, for example, by timing-out, the actual synchronous code will keep running and using system resources until it finishes naturally.
The only fix for that is to create a state which can be checked inside the sync code (for example, an instance attribute, or a value posted to a Queue (thread-oriented queue from queue.Queue, not asyncio.Queue)
As a side note, Python code in a module is executed in order - you call to the main() function must be at the botton. The if __name__ ... device is not mandatory - it is a thing that Can be used and allows your module to either be importable into a larger project, or run as an standalone app. If it is not meant to be imported, just call main() in the last line, at the module level.
